# Swift: Is there any way to hide files from users?

Tags: ios, security

I want to know if there is a place in ios devices where I can store video files in a way such that:

1) Users are not able to find video files outside the app.

2) No other app can read the video files.

3) Even jail-broken devices can't access the video files outside the app.

The only way I want these video files to be accessed is through the app only.

Please help me to know where to save the files.

Comment: File system https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: @karthikeyan thanks for your reply, so is it possible or not?

Comment: @karthikeyan I am concerned about jail broken devices? Can they pull the video files?

Comment: Why don't you encrypt the files properly, then if they access it can't do anything with them?

Comment: @BencePattogato because after encryption it hard to play the videos.

Comment: Then you can decrypt it when it comes to playing them :D

Comment: @BencePattogato yes but there is no good way to do so, without third party library.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption?language=objc

Comment: "Symmetric. Symmetric encryption is good for bulk data transfer because it’s computationally efficient and operates on streams of data." you will have the private key, store it in keychain safely and use that to encrypt your video files.

Comment: @BencePattogato there is no documentations on how to encrypt and decrypt video files in swift. It seems uncommon.

Comment: @BencePattogato if keychain is safe from jail break, why video files can't be stored in some where safe too?

Comment: There is no way to prevent a file being read on a jail broken device. Encryption is the best way to protect content on a jailbroken device.

Comment: @Paulw11 but how to do the encryption and how to play and decrypt?

Comment: The keychain can also be accessed on a jailbroken device but by using encryption you make it more difficult; an attacker needs to search the keychain, identify the key and then use it to decrypt the file. You cannot securely store a piece of information on a device that you don't control. You would need to read the file in "chunks", decrypt each chunk and pass it to your player

Comment: @Paulw11 no tutorial on how to do this? and it seems that it will slow down the playback, and it seems that seeking the video would become hard?

Comment: The decryption overhead shouldn't be that great using a symmetrical key encryption algorithm, and the encryption process doesn't change the number of bytes; the ciphertext is the same size as the cleartext so seeking shouldn't be any different.   You could also look at using Apple's FairPlay system

Comment: @Paulw11 what is apple fair play?

Comment: There is lot of article related to video encryption and decryption why dont you go with https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor and they are giving key based encryption make sure your key should be comes from your server(If your videos comes from server). I am not sure about implementation but you can try it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at link posted by @karthikeyan.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Choose the right 'SearchPathDomainMask'.

```
let documents = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

From Apple Library:

```
public struct SearchPathDomainMask : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var userDomainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get } 
    // user's home directory --- place to install user's personal items (~)

    public static var localDomainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get } 
    // local to the current machine --- place to install items available to everyone on this machine (/Library)

    public static var networkDomainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get }                                           
    // publically available location in the local area network --- place to install items available on the network (/Network)

    public static var systemDomainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get } 
    // provided by Apple, unmodifiable (/System)

    public static var allDomainsMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get } 
    // all domains: all of the above and future items
}
```

Comment: what about jail-broken devices? How to protect video files from these?

Comment: No, you can not protect video files for JailBroken devices. I think there are two options. First is encryption. Second is no installation on Jail Broken devices if data is that sensitive or you want to secure it.